# Calculated column that is for each time series

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have this Power BI file

through this link

> we.tl/t-Q5Fgc0G6ZX

It has data for users and scores per date

the greph looks fine except 1 thing

[image]

This is so far good to show total users counts and passed uses count

but what I want in top of that is to have a 3rd bar shows how many users are needed to get the target of passing users for that month/year/day/quarter

Target is 60% of total number of users

[image: Data1b.png]

How can I do that.

appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your table at the fields pane (right side) and chose `New Column`. Type the following into the expression field:

```
60 Percentage Target = YourTable[NumberOfUsers] * 1,6
```

Now simple drag and drop the `60 Percentage Target` column into your chart (value) and you get your desired result.